# Are there any languages with greetings that could be easily mixed up with other phrases?

Tags: pronunciation, translation

I'm currently writing a script in which a character tries to use a machine translator, but it fails and shocks/offends the person she's trying to talk to. Are there any languages I could use that have a greeting that could be mixed up with a different phrase if pronounced or translated slightly incorrectly?

I tried searching Google, for "languages with greetings that can easily be messed up" but all I could find was "here's how to say hello in 100 different languages.

Comment: Not exactly a greeting, but there is the perennial urban(ish) legend used to scare new students trying to learn the pitfalls of tones in Mandarin: 请问 _qǐng wèn_ (with _wèn_ in the fourth tone) means ‘excuse me, may I ask..?’, whereas 请吻 _qǐng wěn_ (with _wěn_ in the third tone) means ‘please kiss me’ or ‘can I kiss you?’. Except it doesn’t really. It means ‘please kiss’, and without an object it’s an extremely unlikely and strange sentence. In real life, no Mandarin speaker would understand it as anything but a mispronounced ‘may I ask..?’.

Comment: Your research may get more results if you allow cross-language puns. For example, the very word ['hello'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Putin_khuylo!#In_music).

Comment: This is an interesting writing question, but I'm not sure it's a good fit for this site.

Comment: This is a terrrrible question. By one count, there are 7,106 languages in the world and I doubt too many would have this issue. But then, I only know four.

Comment: In many languages a greeting not only can be mixed up with, but literally is "another" phrase like: good day, peace to you (as-salamu alaikum), be healthy (zdravstvuyte), I'm your slave (ciao), etc. A literal interpretation or an interpretation in a different context of one of those phrases might make an interesting plot.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking primarily for written or spoken examples, or would a combination (i.e. the protagonist is trying to read aloud something in an unfamiliar language) work as well?

You are looking for a language with a lot of homonyms, an idiosyncratic orthography, weird and not standardized pronunciation without clear correspondence to the writing... such as English (the second contender is Mandarin).

Well, come. Especially considering the sexual meaning of the second word - and the first one can be also a water hole in the ground.

Good buy.

High. As a greeting.

Hi, Jack! As yelled by a passenger in an airplane seeing his old time friend, as the meme older than internet goes.

Good mourning. Good day. Good knight.

Sea ewe.

And certainly many other examples.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best example, but languages with politeness markers could work.  E.g., in Korean, "안녕 *annyeong*" is a non-polite version of "hello," to be used between children, classmates, siblings, close friends, from parent to child, etc.  In other situations (e.g., between a customer and a cashier), the more polite "안녕하세요 *annyeonghaseyo*" is appropriate.

So one could imagine a situation where a speaker uses machine translator to say "안녕!" to an old cranky person.

(But it's hard to make into a realistic situation, because any reasonable native speaker who looks at a foreigner struggling with a machine translator would immediately understand that it's the translator that's the problem, not the person.)

Comment: The dramatic nature of this admittedly rare situation means that this is a well-exploited (/ over-exploited) Korean drama trope.